# Is exception-propagating decorator a good pattern?

Tags: python, python-decorators

Well-defined custom exceptions are often more informative than builtin ones; e.g. `AgeError` more so than `ValueError`. So in general I try to use the former when I can. But as a consequence of this, my code is littered with lots of `raise foo from bar` boilerplate just to propagate a custom exception. Here is an example of what I mean. Without using custom exceptions, I'd just write:

```
class Person:
    def set_age(self, age_as_string):
        self.age = int(age_as_string)
```

This may raise either `TypeError` or `ValueError`, but since the caller will handle it, a one-liner is just fine.

But to use custom exceptions, I need boilerplate:

```
class AgeError(Exception):
    pass

class Person:
    def set_age(self, age_as_string):
        try:
            self.age = int(age_as_string)
        except (TypeError, ValueError) as e:
            raise AgeError from e
```

This is more informative from the caller's point of view, but costs 300% more code (just counting the method body) and obscures the main business of `set_age`.

Is there a way to have the best of both worlds? I tried googling for solutions but even the problem doesn't seem to be much discussed at all. The solution I eventually come to is use an exception-propagating decorator, which is trivial to write thanks to the wonderful `contextlib` (and only a little less trivial if you need to implement it by hand):

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmananer
def raise_from(to_catch, to_raise):
    try:
        yield
    except to_catch as e:
        raise to_raise from e
```

Now I need only one-extra line, which doesn't obscure the business logic, and even makes the error-handling logic somewhat more obvious (and it's smart-looking):

```
class Person:
    @raise_from(to_catch=(TypeError, ValueError), to_raise=AgeError)
    def set_age(self, age_as_string):
        self.age = int(age_as_string)
```

So I'm quite happy with this solution. But since it's unlikely that there still exists any unsolved problem with an easy solution like this, I'm worried that I may be missing something. Are there disadvantages with using the `raise_from` decorator that I haven't considered? Or is the very need to reduce the `raise foo from bar` boilerplate an indication that I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing wrong with your `raise_from` context manager, but the slight issue worth pointing out is that you're using it as a function decorator, which applies the exception mapping logics to the entire body of the function. This can be problematic when the function is not a one-liner like the `set_age` method in your example, since multiple statements in the function may raise the same exception for different reasons.

For example, you definitely don't want `AgeError` to be raised when it's caused by `int(weight_as_string)`:

```
class Person:
    @raise_from(to_catch=(TypeError, ValueError), to_raise=AgeError)
    def __init__(self, age_as_string, weight_as_string):
        self.age = int(age_as_string)
        self.weight = int(weight_as_string)
```

So to keep the scope of the exception handler as narrow as possible, it is generally better to use `raise_from` as a context manager instead of a decorator:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, age_as_string, weight_as_string):
        with raise_from(to_catch=(TypeError, ValueError), to_raise=AgeError):
            self.age = int(age_as_string)
        with raise_from(to_catch=(TypeError, ValueError), to_raise=WeightError):
            self.weight = int(weight_as_string)
```